# SQL Server 2008 R2 Not able to resolve Merge conflict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I am running a merge replication. During the merge process there is a conflict.  If I choose the winner, the conflict just comes back. If I choose a loser, I get an error.

> TITLE: Microsoft Replication Conflict Viewer
>
> Microsoft Replication Conflict Viewer encountered an error executing the following query:
>
> set DATEFORMAT mdy  if (select OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[tABLE]'),'TableHasIdentity')) =1
>
> [SQL INSERT STATEMENT]
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint in database [Database], replicated table [TABLE]. , column [TABLE]. If the identity column is automatically managed by replication, update the range as follows: for the Publisher, execute sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.
>   The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 548)

I have run `sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange` to fix this, but it does not resolve the issue or change the range on the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found orphaned records in the subscriber.  Once deleted, the conflicts resolved themselves.